# Submit data to database using Inertia/React in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, eloquent, inertiajs

I have a form that is supposed to submit order details to the `orders` table through a custom select element (headlessUI Combobox). The element works fine but I can't seem to pass the data selected to the database, in this case, `customer_id`.

Here's the form on the `Create.js` page:

```js
export default function Create(props) {

     const [selected, setSelected] = useState(""), 
           {customers} = usePage().props

     const {post, processing, data, setData} = useForm({
          customer_id: "",
          
          // other fields here
     })

     const customerList = customers.map((customer, index) => (
         {key: customer.id, name: customer.name}
     ))

     const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        data.customer_id = selected.key
        post(route('resources.orders.store'), data)   
     }

     <Form submit={submit}>
         <SelectSearch options={customerList} name={customer_id} value={selected}
              onChange={setSelected} />
   
         {/* other form elements in here */}
      
         <Button processing={processing} />
     </Form>

}
```

When I `console.log(data)` I get the selected value in the console: `customer_id: 4`. When I `dd($request->all())` I get the array:

```php
^ array:5 [▼
  "order_date" => "2022-05-14"
  "customer_id" => 5
  "service_id" => "3"
  "quantity" => "1"
  "discount" => "0"
]
```

But I get the Error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'customer_id' doesn't have a default value` when the data is submitted. The `customer_id` is a `foreignId()` field. I can't seem to create the record.

Answer (score 0):

First issue could be you have made an error and are not sending the required data in the request.

To test if this is true use the dd() function within the controller method that handles the request for storing the data if sticking to convention that will be the store() method. Pass the $request variable to the dd() function and chain the all method to retrieve everything in the request.

Example

dd($request->all());

This will show all of the variables within the request and you can check to see if the data you expect is there.

Second thing it could be is the orders model navigate to the models directory and open order model class then check that you have added customer_id to the fillable property’s array.

protected $fillable = [‘customer_id’];

Please note all database fields that you intend to insert or update MUST be present within this array.

Comment: My model `$fillable[]` array has got the `customer_id` field as fillable. I think the problem is in the frontend because I can't seem to pass only that piece of information, since I'm using a custom input component (headlessUI) in React.

Comment: I think the `customer_id` field is not being passed properly. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I had to pick the value of the custom input and append it to `data.customer_id` in the submit method:

```js
const submit = (e) => {
    data.customer_id = document.querySelector('[name="customer_id[id]"]').value
    post(route("resources.orders.store"), data)
}
```

The Headless UI Combobox component renders hidden input(s) that stores the values you select. So I had to just append the value of that hidden input to the `data.customer_id`. Then I had to also change my `store()` method:

```php
public function store(StoreOrderRequest $request) : RedirectResponse
    {
        Order::create([
            $request->validated(),
            'customer_id' => $request->customer_id,
            'order_date' => $request->order_date,
            'service_id' => $request->service_id,
            'discount' => $request->discount,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'updated_by' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);

    }
```